# Changes in IDENTITY column after EF core 3

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Until EF core version used in .donet core 2.2, after the `.Add` command, EF fills the key column with a big negative number.

After 3.0 upgrade this does not happens anymore.

Here is the code:

```
var appointment = new Appointment
{
    Date = DateTime.Today,
    ProfessionalId = schedule.ProfessionalId
};
await service.AddAsync(appointment);

string message = null;
if (service.AddLastPrescription(appointment.Id, schedule.PacienteId))
 ....
```

The problem is that now the "appointment.Id" is zero and the call to the service function will fail (FK error).

This behavior was expected in 3.0?

### update

AddAsync function

```
private DbSet<T> dbSet;

public async Task AddAsync(T t)
{
    await dbSet.AddAsync(t);
}
```

where T is ModelBase:

```
public class ModelBase
{

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> This behavior was expected in 3.0?

Yes, it is one of the [3.0 Breaking Changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes) - [Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#temporary-key-values-are-no-longer-set-onto-entity-instances).

The proposed solutions there are:

> - Not using store-generated keys.
> - Setting navigation properties to form relationships instead of setting foreign key values.
> - Obtain the actual temporary key values from the entity's tracking information. For example, `context.Entry(blog).Property(e => e.Id).CurrentValu`e will return the temporary value even though `blog.Id` itself hasn't been set.

Option #1 doesn't make sense (apparently the affected places already use store generated keys).

Option #2 is preferable if you have navigation properties.

Option #3 is closer to the previous behavior, but requires access to the db context.

Comment: Not sure how exactly `context.Entry(blog).Property(e => e.Id).CurrentValue` works? will it give the actual primary key value from database? If it is then what will happen if multiple insertion happen at the same time?

Comment: @Tanvir It works the same way PK property of the object (`blog.Id`) worked in 2.x, i.e. initially will have temporary generated value.