# After upgrade to EF Core 2.2 => 3.1, Guid ID no longer generated by DbSet.Add()

Tags: dotconnect, entity-framework-core-3.0, entity-framework-core-3.1

I'm upgrading from EF Core 2.2 to EF Core 3.1.   I have an entity Patient with a GUID Id:

```
class Patient { 
   public Guid Id { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

A DbSet is defined for this type:

`public DbSet<Patient> Patients { get; set; }`

In EF 2.2, when I added a new Patient, the Id would be automatically generated when the object was added to the DbSet:

```
// newPatient.Id -> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ctx.Patients.Add(newPatient);
// newPatient.Id -> C1D5ACB8-A4C9-4680-AF2F-BF5E5B0AC1B6     <=== GUID generated
```

Now, in EF 3.1, the Id is not being automatically generated upon Add:

```
// newPatient.Id -> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ctx.Patients.Add(newPatient);
// newPatient.Id -> 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000     <=== still an empty GUID
```

This obviously breaks my code.

In EF Core 3.0 there is a breaking change "[String and byte array keys are not client-generated by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#string-and-byte-array-keys-are-not-client-generated-by-default)". However, this breaking change indicates string and byte array keys, not GUID keys.   Also, I have tried the recommended mitigations with FluentAPI and Data Annotations and it does not resolve my issue (still no GUID generated).

I am using the [dotConnect for Oracle](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) database provider v9.11.  I did not find any breaking changes there that would affect this.

Of course I can explicitly assign a GUID Id in my code, but I'd like to make this work as it did before in EF Core 2.2.

Any suggestions why this is not working?   Thanks.

Comment: Probably the same reason as for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58147041/changes-in-identity-column-after-ef-core-3/58147159#58147159, i.e. breaking change [Temporary key values are no longer set onto entity instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#temporary-key-values-are-no-longer-set-onto-entity-instances)

Comment: @IvanStoev good find, I hadn't see that post.  I saw that breaking change but I didn't think it fit because the Guid was always the permanent key, however that's probably because it's a Guid and not an autogenerated ID.

Comment: It probably depends on the provider. For SqlServer by default the generated Guids are permanent and are set onto entity. But when configured with `HasDefaultValueSql("newid()")` the generated Guids are temporary and are not set onto entity.